# Node js JWT token not generated with RS256 algorithm

Tags: node.js, jwt, express-jwt

I used JWT to protect my node.js REST api calls.
I used below code to generate the token:

```
jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, private_key, { algorithm: 'RS256'}, (err, token) => {
      res.json({
        token
      });
```

But I don't get any token with when I use the algorithm: 'RS256'. But above code works with algorithm: 'HS256'.

Do you know a solution?

Comment: You didn't show what private key actually is. Do you get any errors? Please click on edit to complete the code above and add more information to your question.

Comment: What npm package are you using to try and generate the JWT? Also please add `console.log(err, token);` to your code and report the results.

Comment: quite a waste of time, if you just dump your uncomplete questions and then don't react anymore

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, private_key, [{ algorithm: 'RS256'}, (err, token) => {
  res.json({
    token
  }}]);
```

In npm docs appear this `jwt.sign(payload, secretOrPrivateKey, [options, callback])` so pass your options and callback like an array. Hope this help

Comment: ```[options, callback]``` this means optional